# Link not showing inside <td> tags

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to include a link within `<td></td>`, but it's not showing at all.

```
<tr align=left>
    <td><span style="font-weight:bold;">Website</span></td>                       
    <td><a href="http://www.zionsb.org"></a></td>
</tr>
```

**CSS**

```
td {  
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 115%;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;        
}
```

Please where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must have some content in your link for it to be visible. For example :

```
<a href="http://www.zionsb.org">some text</a>
```

---

You could also bind the click event to the cell if you have nothing to display :

```
<td id=A style="cursor:pointer"></td>

<script>
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('A').onclick=function(){window.location="http://www.zionsb.org"};
};
</script>
```

but that wouldn't alone make the link visible.

Answer (score 3):

You've successfully made a link, but now need to say what the link is to!
Between your:

```
<a> and </a>
```

tag, you must put the words that you want to be seen. For example:

```
<a href="http://www.zionsb.org">Text you want to be seen</a>
```